# Firebase v3 - Handling Unverified Password-Based Users?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I handle user sessions in case password-based auth user has not yet verified their email address using the [custom email action handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)?

Specifically, I have a chip in the upper right corner of my Web app displaying the `displayName` of the signed in user.  Handling the signed in user as unverified in my app logic is no problem except they are technically signed in and need a way to sign out.

Showing a sign out button is a bit misleading bcs they have no privileges until their email is validated.  Showing "visitor" also seems odd.

How should I handle this scenario?

```
var myAppName = (function() {
    var pub = {};
    pub.doc = document;
    var doc = pub.doc;

    pub.email;
    pub.displayName;
    pub.photoUrl;
    pub.uid;
    pub.validUser = false;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

        pub.loadUserVariables();

        if (user) {
            var provider = firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId;
            var verified = firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified;         

            switch(provider) {
                case 'facebook':
                    pub.validUser = true;
                    break;
                case 'github':
                    pub.validUser = true;
                    break;
                case 'google':
                    pub.validUser = true;
                    break;
                case 'password':
                    if(verified){
                        pub.validUser = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'twitter':
                    pub.validUser = true;
                    break;
                //var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
            }

            //window.location ='/';
            pub.putNewUser();
        } else {
            //window.location ='/login';
        }
    });
    //API
    return pub;
}());
```

Comment: Most apps allow an unverified account to sign in: authentication <> authorization. Some apps allow the user to temporarily use the app, but some also immediately put them in a "holding state"; essentially a screen that tells them to click the link in the verification email.

Comment: Thanks.  I was kinda thinking of that.  just check `firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified` on dom load and set `window.location` to holding page.

Comment: Good to hear. Have fun!